# No puedo eliminar un archivo en c++

Tags: c++

Necesito borrar el archivo original y dejar el otro archivo copia para renombrarlo con el nombre del archivo original, pero no sé por qué no me funciona.

Agradecería que me ayudaran.

```
remove("Fichero.txt");
rename("Temp.txt","Fichero.txt");


#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int clave, Bclave, opcion;
    char nombre[30];
    ofstream Guardar;
    ifstream mostrar;
    ofstream Temp;

    Guardar.open("Fichero.txt",ios::app);
    while(true){
        cout<<"Ingresar opcion"<<endl;
        cout<<"1 Ingresar datos"<<endl;
        cout<<"2 Mostrar datos"<<endl;
        cout<<"3 Buscar datos"<<endl;
        cout<<"4 Eliminar datos"<<endl;

        Temp.close();
        mostrar.close();

        cin>>opcion;

        switch(opcion){

        case 1:{
            cout<<"Ingrese el nombre"<<endl;
            cin>>nombre;
            cout<<"Ingrese la clave"<<endl;
            cin>>clave;
            Guardar<<nombre<<" "<<clave<<endl;
            break;
        }

        case 2:{
                mostrar.open("Fichero.txt");
                mostrar>>nombre;
                while(!mostrar.eof()){
                    mostrar>>clave;
                    cout<<"Nombre "<<nombre<<endl;
                    cout<<"Clave "<<clave<<endl;
                    cout<<endl;
                    mostrar>>nombre;
                }
                mostrar.close();
                break;
            }

        case 3:{
                mostrar.open("Fichero.txt");
                mostrar>>nombre;
                bool verificar=false;
                cout<<"Ingrese la clave que desea buscar"<<endl;
                cin>>Bclave;
                while(!mostrar.eof()){
                mostrar>>clave;
                if(clave==Bclave){
                    verificar=true;
                    cout<<endl;
                    cout<<"Nombre "<<nombre<<endl;
                    cout<<"Clave "<<clave<<endl<<endl;
                }
                mostrar>>nombre;
                }
                if(verificar==false){
                    cout<<"Clave no encontrada "<<endl;
                }
                mostrar.close();
                break;
                }

        case 4:{
                    mostrar.open("Fichero.txt");
                    Temp.open("Temp.txt");
                    mostrar>>nombre;
                    bool verificar=false;
                    cout<<"Ingrese la clave que desea buscar"<<endl;
                    cin>>Bclave;
                    while(!mostrar.eof()){
                        mostrar>>clave;
                        if(clave==Bclave){
                            verificar=true;
                            cout<<endl;
                            cout<<"Nombre "<<nombre<<endl;
                            cout<<"Clave "<<clave<<endl<<endl;
                            cout<<"Datos eliminados";
                        }
                        else{
                            Temp<<nombre<<" "<<clave<<endl;
                        }
                        mostrar>>nombre;
                    }
                    if(verificar==false){
                        cout<<"Clave no encontrada "<<endl;
                    }
                    Temp.close();
                    mostrar.close();
                    remove("Fichero.txt");
                    rename("Temp.txt","Fichero.txt");

                    break;

                }
    }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hola max tu error está en que antes de llamar a las funciones remove y rename debes cerrar todos los objetos que tengan abierto el archivo a borrar y a renombrar, cierras Temp y mostrar pero no cierras guardar. Tu problema se soluciona simplemente con esta instruccion justo antes de llamar a los metodos remove y rename:

```
Guardar.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Desconozco exactamente que esta fallando en tu codigo pero justamente ayer hice uno que me funciona y puedes basarte en el, si te funciono no olvides publicarlo, saludos.

```
//Eliminar tabla
char nombre[20];
char alfabeto[26];
char Cifrado[26];
char aux[20];
ifstream salida;
salida.open("Tablas.txt",ios::in);
ofstream entrada;
entrada.open ("Temporal.txt",ios::out);

if(salida.fail()){
    cout<<"Hubo un error al abrir el archivo Tablas.txt";
    getch();
}else{
    cout<<"introduzca el nombre de la tabla que desea eliminar: ";
    cin>>aux;
    salida>>nombre;
    if(strcmp(aux,nombre)){
        cout<<"La tabla no existe"<<endl;
        }
    while(!salida.eof()){
        salida>>Cifrado;
        if(strcmp(aux,nombre)==0){
            cout<<"La tabla se ha Eliminado"<<endl;
            system("pause");
        }else{
            entrada<<nombre<<" "<<Cifrado<<endl;
        }
        salida>>nombre;
    }
}
entrada.close();
salida.close();

remove("Tablas.txt");
rename("Temporal.txt","Tablas.txt");
```